# Pyspark text read to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I know this question is recurrent! but I couldn't find an answer to my question elsewhere. I have this text data:

```
00001 A00     0 Cholera                                                      Cholera
00002 A000    1 Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01  biovar cholerae           Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01  biovar cholerae
00003 A001    1 Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01  biovar eltor              Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01  biovar eltor
00004 A009    1 Cholera  unspecified                                         Cholera  unspecified
```

I used spark  to read it:

```
data= sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "False").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter", "\t" ).load("/path/file.txt")
```

The result :

```
   +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|00001 A00     0 Cholera                                                      Cholera                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|00002 A000    1 Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01  biovar cholerae           Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01  biovar cholerae|
|00003 A001    1 Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01  biovar eltor              Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01  biovar eltor   |
|00004 A009    1 Cholera  unspecified                                         Cholera  unspecified                              |
|00005 A01     0 Typhoid and paratyphoid fevers                               Typhoid and paratyphoid fevers                    |
|00006 A010    0 Typhoid fever                                                Typhoid fever                                     |
|00007 A0100   1 Typhoid fever  unspecified                                   Typhoid fever  unspecified                        |
|00008 A0101   1 Typhoid meningitis                                           Typhoid meningitis                                |
|00009 A0102   1 Typhoid fever with heart involvement                         Typhoid fever with heart involvement              |
|00010 A0103   1 Typhoid pneumonia                                            Typhoid pneumonia                                 |
|00011 A0104   1 Typhoid arthritis                                            Typhoid arthritis                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I expect the output to be a dataframe with 4 columns, like this:

```
--------------+--------------------+--------------------+----+
|DIAGNOSIS CODE|    LONG DESCRIPTION|   SHORT DESCRIPTION| _c3|
+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+----+
|          0010|Cholera due to vi...|Cholera d/t vib c...|null|
|          0011|Cholera due to vi...|Cholera d/t vib e...|null|
|          0019|Cholera, unspecified|         Cholera NOS|null|
|          0020|       Typhoid fever|       Typhoid fever|null|
|          0021| Paratyphoid fever A| Paratyphoid fever a|null|
|          0022| Paratyphoid fever B| Paratyphoid fever b|null|
|          0023| Paratyphoid fever C| Paratyphoid fever c|null|
|          0029|Paratyphoid fever...|Paratyphoid fever...|null|
|          0030|Salmonella gastro...|Salmonella enteritis|null|
|          0031|Salmonella septic...|Salmonella septic...|null|
+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+----+
```

Any advice?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to explain what output you were expecting, and you should also show the entire output, not just the ellipses.

Comment: @tgdavies thank you for your answer. I updated the question. Ideally, I obtain a dataframe with columns not just one column.

Comment: You shouldn't have to escape the slash in `\t`. Try with just one slash.

Answer (score 0):

`sep` is not valid option for spark-csv.
It should be `delimiter`.

[Spark-CSV Features](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#features)

Comment: Same as delimiter.